# Questions about ftps server

Tags: c#, c++, visual-c++, sftp

I already have code for a ftp server. I am following  [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/ftpserver.aspx) code. Now my requirement is to create a ftps server. But my problem is I dont know anything about it. I googled for it. But did not find any useful help. Any suggestion or book name will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: The [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_File_Transfer_Protocol) of SFTP provides both the relevant standard drafts and [a list of server implementations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_SFTP_server_software), several of which open source, I think you have a lot of material to work on...

Comment: Thanks.. any books suggestion ?

Comment: Are there actually books about SFTP? :o

Comment: Just checking. Are you you sure you want SFTP instead of FTPS? SFTP refers to file transfer over SSH. The underlying protocol is very different from normal FTP. FTPS refers to normal FTP, but using SSL for the data and/or control connections.

Comment: @kaliatech Sorry you are correct. Its my mistake. I am asking about ftps.

Comment: Then you have [RFC4217](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4217).

Comment: @ Matteo Italia - Thanks man. Great help.

Comment: Is this a C# question or a C++ question? You have both tags.

Comment: @DBM - Basically C++ but also possible with C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [wikipedia page on FTPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FTPS) is useful as an overview.  I believe there are a few commercial libraries available for implementing an FTP/SSL server in C#, although I'm not familiar with them. Examples:

- http://www.g6ftpserver.com/
- http://www.eldos.com/sbb/net-ftps.php

I don't know of any open-source alternatives. You might try looking at open-source implementations in other languages. Examples:

- [FileZilla Server](http://filezilla-project.org/sourcecode.php) - C++
- [Apache FtpServer](http://mina.apache.org/ftpserver/) - Java (has support for TLS/SSL)